# ffmpeg Create GIF from image sequence and use transparent background

Tags: ffmpeg

What I'm trying to do is to create a gif from images with different sizes and make the borders (padded area) for images that have different aspect ratio transparent.

Each image should be shown for 3 seconds. (-r 1/3)

I created a file list (Lista.txt) from the images I want, the image names are not sequenced so I can't use %03d or something. All files are in *.jpg format.

My code:

```
ffmpeg -f concat -safe 0 -r 1/3 -i Lista.txt -loop 0 -lavfi ^
"[0]format=rgba,scale=854:480:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease:eval=frame,pad=854:480:-1:-1:eval=frame:color=#00000000@0.0[vid]; ^
[vid]split[vid1][vid2];[vid1]palettegen=reserve_transparent=1[pal]; ^
[vid2][pal]paletteuse=alpha_threshold=128[final]" -map [final] -gifflags -offsetting "output.gif"
```

The end result output.gif shows only the last image of the sequence and not all the images. Any help would be appreciated.

These are the images:
[Images.zip](https://onedrive.live.com/download?cid=8E0E12FBD10DA3C0&resid=8E0E12FBD10DA3C0%2141167&authkey=ALdhCxhieOYrXiI)

This is the result:
[output.gif](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yFTJ3.gif)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like adding `-reinit_filter 0` flag, solves the issue:

```
ffmpeg -f concat -safe 0 -reinit_filter 0 -r 1/3 -i Lista.txt -loop 0 -lavfi ^
"[0]format=rgba,scale=854:480:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease:eval=frame,pad=854:480:-1:-1:eval=frame:color=#00000000@0.0[vid]; ^
[vid]split[vid1][vid2];[vid1]palettegen=reserve_transparent=1[pal]; ^
[vid2][pal]paletteuse=alpha_threshold=128[final]" -map [final] -gifflags -offsetting "output.gif"
```

---

Downscaled output:

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much. Any idea why the video has to be duplicated with split, it doesn't seem to work without that part. I copied the palettegen part from another topic and I got that is necessary for some reason for transparency with gif files but I didn't get why the video has to be duplicated, then a palete is created with one of the copies, then the palete is mixed with the other copy that looks wierd for me, but I'm no ffmpeg expert...

Comment: `[vid1]` is consumed by `palettegen` filter, and `[vid2]` is consumed by `paletteuse` filter. When building a filter-graph, we can use the same input twice (unless it's a "primary input" like `0:v`) I think. I'm no ffmpeg expert eather...

Comment: That got through my head too, hä??? is that part used with palettegen beeing consumed somhow so I can't use it later? So all the input's that are created that one may call aliases or nickname can only be used once? I didn't notice this before....